# Safaricom Daraja: Duplicate json key detected

Tags: json, python-3.x, django, django-rest-framework

I am implementing Lipa na M-Pesa online by Safaricom. However, when I make the request, I get an error saying duplicate json keys detected.

The Payload:

```json
payload = {
    "BusinessShortCode": 174379, 
    "Password": "the password", 
    "Timestamp": "20220817050503", 
    "TransactionType": "CustomerPayBillOnline", 
    "Amount": 5, 
    "PartyA": 254714895622, 
    "PartyB": 174379, 
    "PhoneNumber": 254714895622, 
    "CallBackURL": "https://58fa-102-68-78-50.in.ngrok.io/api/v1/payments/callback/", 
    "AccountReference": "Payment", 
    "TransactionDesc": "Payment for K"
}
```

The headers:

```json
headers = {
    "Content-Type": "application/json",
    "Authorization": "Bearer access_token",
}
```

The request:

```py
response = requests.request("POST", 'https://sandbox.safaricom.co.ke/mpesa/stkpush/v1/processrequest', headers=headers, data=payload)
```

The response I get:

```json
{
   'responseId': '82699-21939686', 
   'responseCode': '400', 
   'responseDesc': 'Duplicate json key detected'
}
```

What could be the cause of this error and how can I go about solving it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is in the header, the request passes the `Content-Type` by default,
getting rid of it fixes the problem.

Answer (score 3):

Although it is provided for in Safaricom's M-pesa Daraja code sample for python, Try changing this part so that it would be; renaming `body=payload` to `json=payload`

```
response = requests.request("POST",your-url, headers=headers, json=payload)
```

instead of

```
response = requests.request("POST", url , headers=headers, data=payload)
```

Removing `Content-Type` from the header as suggested gave me another error;

```
{'requestId': '12345-12345-1',
'errorCode': '400.002.02',
'errorMessage': 'Bad Request - Invalid BusinessShortCode'}
```

worked for me hope it does for you

Comment: This. sending the payload using json instead of data worked for me both with and without the 'Content-Type' header

Answer (score 0):

The following works

```
import requests

headers = {
  'Content-Type': 'application/json',
  'Authorization': 'Bearer DWbh63zkq7ZLagmNCSwnyvjA2kBQ'
}

payload = {
    "BusinessShortCode": 174379,
    "Password": "MTc0Mzc5YmZiMjc5ZjlhYTliZGJjZjE1OGU5N2RkNzFhNDY3Y2QyZTBjODkzMDU5YjEwZjc4ZTZiNzJhZGExZWQyYzkxOTIwMjIxMjIyMDUyOTQ5",
    "Timestamp": "20221222052949",
    "TransactionType": "CustomerPayBillOnline",
    "Amount": 1,
    "PartyA": 254712345678,
    "PartyB": 174379,
    "PhoneNumber": 254712345678,
    "CallBackURL": "example.com/path",
    "AccountReference": "CompanyXLTD",
    "TransactionDesc": "Payment of X" 
  }

response = requests.request("POST", 'example.com/mpesa/stkpush/v1/processrequest', headers = headers, json = payload)
print(response.text.encode('utf8'))
```

Answer (score 0):

use `response = requests.post(mpesa_url,headers=headers,json=payload )` to fix Duplicate json key detected the error and also remember to generate a new password in the payload you can use the following code

`{ import base64  def generate_stk_password(shortcode, passkey, timestamp): plaintext = str(shortcode) + passkey + timestamp password = base64.b64encode(plaintext.encode()).decode('utf-8') return password }`

the payload should now look like this

payload  = {

```
"BusinessShortCode": 174379,

"Password": f"{generate_stk_password(short_code,passkey,datetime.datetime.now().strftime('%Y%m%d%H%M%S'))}",
"Timestamp": f"{datetime.datetime.now().strftime('%Y%m%d%H%M%S')}",

"TransactionType": "CustomerPayBillOnline",
"Amount": amount,

"PartyA": phone_number,

"PartyB": 174379,

"PhoneNumber": 254790349244,

"CallBackURL": "example.com",

"AccountReference": "CompanyXLTD",

"TransactionDesc": "Payment of X"
```

}

Hope this fixes your problem.